# Does android support .jks keystore type?

Tags: android, ssl, keystore

I am trying to connect to server using keystore which is provided by server team.

While sending service call  to server first i created KeyStore Instance by using following api

```
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
```

It’s returning the keystore type as “BKS”.

The Keystore what server team sent is of type “.jks”(somename.jks) So, I am getting exception “Wrong version of key store”.

I tried by passing “JKS” to getInstance() of KeyStore by following way

```
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
```

But here I am getting exception “KeyStore JKS implementation not found”.

Here is the piece of code:

```
KeyStore trustStore  = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

InputStream instream = mContext.getAssets().open("somename.jks");

try {
    trustStore.load(instream, "password".toCharArray());
} finally {
    try {
       instream.close();
    } catch(Exception ignore) {
    }
}
```

Please guide me to solve this problem.

Comment: "jks" seems to be default. If this KeyStore is of type "jks", key must be encoded conform to the PKS#8 standard as an EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.  taken from here http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStore.html#getType() and http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.html

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think Android support 'only' BouncyCastle KeyStores (known as BKS)...
You still can use [Portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/)

To convert it from JKS to BKS, should work like a charm (at least it worked for me when trying to store my .CRT into a BKS format ! ;)

'only' meaning, easily here :p, else you'll have to manipulate stuffs

Comment: Yup, JKS is a sun/oracle-proprietary format and I guess Google didn't feel like a few more frivolous lawsuits.

Comment: @Cehm what you said is correct, android is supporting only BKS. I got the BKS keystore from server team and it's worked like charm with same piece of code.

Comment: yes seems android dont support JKS.. also KeyStore.getDefaultType(); returns "BKS"

Comment: @Cehm : Thank you for Portecle, I was having similar problem, but BKS is not working on android for me. Can you please check this SO question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36764841/android-bks-keystore-throwing-error-for-connecting-to-https

Answer (score 0):

Other option is to use KeyStore Explorer (downloadable executable for Mac and Windows available online) to switch to BKS (Bouncy Castle KeyStore).  Should work good for Android. I had similar issues while using JKS.