# Converting SSL code from regular Java application to SSL code for Android

Tags: java, android, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a regular java application that connects to my java server using the following code:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("cert.jks");
ks.load(inputStream, "password".toCharArray());
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
tmf.init(ks);
SSLContext ssc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
ssc.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
SSLSocketFactory factory = ssc.getSocketFactory();
Socket socket = new Socket(Proxy.NO_PROXY);
InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName("<ip address of server">);
int port = <some port>;
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
SSLSocket ssls = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket(socket, host.getHostAddress(), port, false);
ssls.setUseClientMode(true);
ssls.setNeedClientAuth(false);
ssls.startHandshake();
```

And everything works fine. However, since Android doesn't support JKS Keystores or SunX509, I've had to make some changes. I've converted the JKS certificate to a BKS certificate using bouncy castle (hat tip to: [How to create a BKS (BouncyCastle) format Java Keystore that contains a client certificate chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065379/how-to-create-a-bks-bouncycastle-format-java-keystore-that-contains-a-client-c)) and used the TrustManagerFactory's default algorithm, so now my code looks like this:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
android.content.res.Resources res = <getter for resources>;
InputStream inputStream = res.openRawResources(R.raw.cert); //The converted bks certificate stored in the raw directory
ks.load(inputStream, "password".toCharArray());
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
tmf.init(ks);
SSLContext ssc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
ssc.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
... same as above ...
ssls.startHandshake();
```

However, the above code throws an exception at the last line of startHandshake:

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer                                   at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)                           at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:324)

What's the issue here? Is there any additional information that can help?

Comment: Hi! Together with the Google's sample code in my answer, if you use self-signed certificate, you can read my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32969952/android-to-server-communication-using-ssl-with-bouncy-castle/32980130#32980130

Answer (score 0):

```
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("cert.bks"); //The converted bks certificate
```

You should put your `cert.bks` file into `/res/raw` directory, then open the file with `getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.cert);`.

EDIT:

I think you are not specifying the provider when you are loading the truststore.

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS", BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
```

And if you forgot, you need to add the SpongyCastle provider in your `Application` class.

```
public class CustomApplication
        extends Application {
    static {
        Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
    }
```

And add that to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:name=".application.CustomApplication"
```

But if that **still doesn't work**, what you can try to do is adding the following classes from the source of [Apache HttpClient](http://archive.apache.org/dist/httpcomponents/httpclient-android/source/httpcomponents-client-android-4.3.5.1-src.zip) (it's apache-licensed so you can do that):

- Args.java

.

```
import java.util.Collection;

class Args {

    public static void check(final boolean expression, final String message) {
        if (!expression) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(message);
        }
    }

    public static void check(final boolean expression, final String message, final Object... args) {
        if (!expression) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format(message, args));
        }
    }

    public static void check(final boolean expression, final String message, final Object arg) {
        if (!expression) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format(message, arg));
        }
    }

    public static <T> T notNull(final T argument, final String name) {
        if (argument == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(name + " may not be null");
        }
        return argument;
    }

    public static <T extends CharSequence> T notEmpty(final T argument, final String name) {
        if (argument == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(name + " may not be null");
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(argument)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(name + " may not be empty");
        }
        return argument;
    }

    public static <T extends CharSequence> T notBlank(final T argument, final String name) {
        if (argument == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(name + " may not be null");
        }
        if (TextUtils.isBlank(argument)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(name + " may not be blank");
        }
        return argument;
    }

    public static <T extends CharSequence> T containsNoBlanks(final T argument, final String name) {
        if (argument == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(name + " may not be null");
        }
        if (TextUtils.containsBlanks(argument)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(name + " may not contain blanks");
        }
        return argument;
    }

    public static <E, T extends Collection<E>> T notEmpty(final T argument, final String name) {
        if (argument == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(name + " may not be null");
        }
        if (argument.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(name + " may not be empty");
        }
        return argument;
    }

    public static int positive(final int n, final String name) {
        if (n <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(name + " may not be negative or zero");
        }
        return n;
    }

    public static long positive(final long n, final String name) {
        if (n <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(name + " may not be negative or zero");
        }
        return n;
    }

    public static int notNegative(final int n, final String name) {
        if (n < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(name + " may not be negative");
        }
        return n;
    }

    public static long notNegative(final long n, final String name) {
        if (n < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(name + " may not be negative");
        }
        return n;
    }
}
```

- PrivateKeyDetails.java

.

```
/*
 * ====================================================================
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 
 *
 *   [...add this back]
 */
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Private key details.
 *
 * @since 4.4
 */
public final class PrivateKeyDetails {
    private final String type;
    private final X509Certificate[] certChain;

    public PrivateKeyDetails(final String type, final X509Certificate[] certChain) {
        super();
        this.type = Args.notNull(type, "Private key type");
        this.certChain = certChain;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public X509Certificate[] getCertChain() {
        return certChain;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return type + ':' + Arrays.toString(certChain);
    }
}
```

- PrivateKeyStrategy.java

.

```
/*
 * ====================================================================
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) [...add this back]
 *
 */
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * A strategy allowing for a choice of an alias during SSL authentication.
 *
 * @since 4.4
 */
public interface PrivateKeyStrategy {
    /**
     * Determines what key material to use for SSL authentication.
     *
     * @param aliases available private key material
     * @param socket  socket used for the connection. Please note this parameter can be {@code null}
     *                if key material is applicable to any socket.
     */
    String chooseAlias(Map<String, PrivateKeyDetails> aliases, Socket socket);
}
```

- SSLContextBuilder.java

.

```
/*
 * ====================================================================
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) [...add this back]
 *
 */

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.Principal;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManager;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.X509ExtendedKeyManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

/**
 * Builder for {@link javax.net.ssl.SSLContext} instances.
 * <p>
 * Please note: the default Oracle JSSE implementation of {@link SSLContext#init(KeyManager[], TrustManager[], SecureRandom)}
 * accepts multiple key and trust managers, however only only first matching type is ever used.
 * See for example:
 * <a href="http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html#init%28javax.net.ssl.KeyManager[],%20javax.net.ssl.TrustManager[],%20java.security.SecureRandom%29">
 * SSLContext.html#init
 * </a>
 *
 * @since 4.4
 */
public class SSLContextBuilder {

    static final String TLS   = "TLS";

    private String protocol;
    private final Set<KeyManager> keymanagers;
    private final Set<TrustManager> trustmanagers;
    private SecureRandom secureRandom;

    public static SSLContextBuilder create() {
        return new SSLContextBuilder();
    }

    public SSLContextBuilder() {
        super();
        this.keymanagers = new LinkedHashSet<KeyManager>();
        this.trustmanagers = new LinkedHashSet<TrustManager>();
    }

    public SSLContextBuilder useProtocol(final String protocol) {
        this.protocol = protocol;
        return this;
    }

    public SSLContextBuilder setSecureRandom(final SecureRandom secureRandom) {
        this.secureRandom = secureRandom;
        return this;
    }

    public SSLContextBuilder loadTrustMaterial(
            final KeyStore truststore,
            final TrustStrategy trustStrategy) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException {
        final TrustManagerFactory tmfactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(
                TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmfactory.init(truststore);
        final TrustManager[] tms = tmfactory.getTrustManagers();
        if (tms != null) {
            if (trustStrategy != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < tms.length; i++) {
                    final TrustManager tm = tms[i];
                    if (tm instanceof X509TrustManager) {
                        tms[i] = new TrustManagerDelegate(
                                (X509TrustManager) tm, trustStrategy);
                    }
                }
            }
            for (final TrustManager tm : tms) {
                this.trustmanagers.add(tm);
            }
        }
        return this;
    }

    public SSLContextBuilder loadTrustMaterial(
            final TrustStrategy trustStrategy) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException {
        return loadTrustMaterial(null, trustStrategy);
    }

    public SSLContextBuilder loadTrustMaterial(
            final File file,
            final char[] storePassword,
            final TrustStrategy trustStrategy) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, CertificateException, IOException {
        Args.notNull(file, "Truststore file");
        final KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        final FileInputStream instream = new FileInputStream(file);
        try {
            trustStore.load(instream, storePassword);
        } finally {
            instream.close();
        }
        return loadTrustMaterial(trustStore, trustStrategy);
    }

    public SSLContextBuilder loadTrustMaterial(
            final File file,
            final char[] storePassword) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, CertificateException, IOException {
        return loadTrustMaterial(file, storePassword, null);
    }

    public SSLContextBuilder loadTrustMaterial(
            final File file) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, CertificateException, IOException {
        return loadTrustMaterial(file, null);
    }

    public SSLContextBuilder loadTrustMaterial(
            final URL url,
            final char[] storePassword,
            final TrustStrategy trustStrategy) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, CertificateException, IOException {
        Args.notNull(url, "Truststore URL");
        final KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        final InputStream instream = url.openStream();
        try {
            trustStore.load(instream, storePassword);
        } finally {
            instream.close();
        }
        return loadTrustMaterial(trustStore, trustStrategy);
    }

    public SSLContextBuilder loadTrustMaterial(
            final URL url,
            final char[] storePassword) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, CertificateException, IOException {
        return loadTrustMaterial(url, storePassword, null);
    }

    public SSLContextBuilder loadKeyMaterial(
            final KeyStore keystore,
            final char[] keyPassword,
            final PrivateKeyStrategy aliasStrategy)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        final KeyManagerFactory kmfactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(
                KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        kmfactory.init(keystore, keyPassword);
        final KeyManager[] kms =  kmfactory.getKeyManagers();
        if (kms != null) {
            if (aliasStrategy != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < kms.length; i++) {
                    final KeyManager km = kms[i];
                    if (km instanceof X509ExtendedKeyManager) {
                        kms[i] = new KeyManagerDelegate((X509ExtendedKeyManager) km, aliasStrategy);
                    }
                }
            }
            for (final KeyManager km : kms) {
                keymanagers.add(km);
            }
        }
        return this;
    }

    public SSLContextBuilder loadKeyMaterial(
            final KeyStore keystore,
            final char[] keyPassword) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        return loadKeyMaterial(keystore, keyPassword, null);
    }

    public SSLContextBuilder loadKeyMaterial(
            final File file,
            final char[] storePassword,
            final char[] keyPassword,
            final PrivateKeyStrategy aliasStrategy) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException, CertificateException, IOException {
        Args.notNull(file, "Keystore file");
        final KeyStore identityStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        final FileInputStream instream = new FileInputStream(file);
        try {
            identityStore.load(instream, storePassword);
        } finally {
            instream.close();
        }
        return loadKeyMaterial(identityStore, keyPassword, aliasStrategy);
    }

    public SSLContextBuilder loadKeyMaterial(
            final File file,
            final char[] storePassword,
            final char[] keyPassword) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException, CertificateException, IOException {
        return loadKeyMaterial(file, storePassword, keyPassword, null);
    }

    public SSLContextBuilder loadKeyMaterial(
            final URL url,
            final char[] storePassword,
            final char[] keyPassword,
            final PrivateKeyStrategy aliasStrategy) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException, CertificateException, IOException {
        Args.notNull(url, "Keystore URL");
        final KeyStore identityStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        final InputStream instream = url.openStream();
        try {
            identityStore.load(instream, storePassword);
        } finally {
            instream.close();
        }
        return loadKeyMaterial(identityStore, keyPassword, aliasStrategy);
    }

    public SSLContextBuilder loadKeyMaterial(
            final URL url,
            final char[] storePassword,
            final char[] keyPassword) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException, CertificateException, IOException {
        return loadKeyMaterial(url, storePassword, keyPassword, null);
    }

    protected void initSSLContext(
            final SSLContext sslcontext,
            final Collection<KeyManager> keyManagers,
            final Collection<TrustManager> trustManagers,
            final SecureRandom secureRandom) throws KeyManagementException {
        sslcontext.init(
                !keyManagers.isEmpty() ? keyManagers.toArray(new KeyManager[keyManagers.size()]) : null,
                !trustManagers.isEmpty() ? trustManagers.toArray(new TrustManager[trustManagers.size()]) : null,
                secureRandom);
    }

    public SSLContext build() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
        final SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance(
                this.protocol != null ? this.protocol : TLS);
        initSSLContext(sslcontext, keymanagers, trustmanagers, secureRandom);
        return sslcontext;
    }

    static class TrustManagerDelegate implements X509TrustManager {

        private final X509TrustManager trustManager;
        private final TrustStrategy trustStrategy;

        TrustManagerDelegate(final X509TrustManager trustManager, final TrustStrategy trustStrategy) {
            super();
            this.trustManager = trustManager;
            this.trustStrategy = trustStrategy;
        }

        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(
                final X509Certificate[] chain, final String authType) throws CertificateException {
            this.trustManager.checkClientTrusted(chain, authType);
        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(
                final X509Certificate[] chain, final String authType) throws CertificateException {
            if (!this.trustStrategy.isTrusted(chain, authType)) {
                this.trustManager.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return this.trustManager.getAcceptedIssuers();
        }

    }

    static class KeyManagerDelegate extends X509ExtendedKeyManager {

        private final X509ExtendedKeyManager keyManager;
        private final PrivateKeyStrategy aliasStrategy;

        KeyManagerDelegate(final X509ExtendedKeyManager keyManager, final PrivateKeyStrategy aliasStrategy) {
            super();
            this.keyManager = keyManager;
            this.aliasStrategy = aliasStrategy;
        }

        @Override
        public String[] getClientAliases(
                final String keyType, final Principal[] issuers) {
            return this.keyManager.getClientAliases(keyType, issuers);
        }

        public Map<String, PrivateKeyDetails> getClientAliasMap(
                final String[] keyTypes, final Principal[] issuers) {
            final Map<String, PrivateKeyDetails> validAliases = new HashMap<String, PrivateKeyDetails>();
            for (final String keyType: keyTypes) {
                final String[] aliases = this.keyManager.getClientAliases(keyType, issuers);
                if (aliases != null) {
                    for (final String alias: aliases) {
                        validAliases.put(alias,
                                new PrivateKeyDetails(keyType, this.keyManager.getCertificateChain(alias)));
                    }
                }
            }
            return validAliases;
        }

        public Map<String, PrivateKeyDetails> getServerAliasMap(
                final String keyType, final Principal[] issuers) {
            final Map<String, PrivateKeyDetails> validAliases = new HashMap<String, PrivateKeyDetails>();
            final String[] aliases = this.keyManager.getServerAliases(keyType, issuers);
            if (aliases != null) {
                for (final String alias: aliases) {
                    validAliases.put(alias,
                            new PrivateKeyDetails(keyType, this.keyManager.getCertificateChain(alias)));
                }
            }
            return validAliases;
        }

        @Override
        public String chooseClientAlias(
                final String[] keyTypes, final Principal[] issuers, final Socket socket) {
            final Map<String, PrivateKeyDetails> validAliases = getClientAliasMap(keyTypes, issuers);
            return this.aliasStrategy.chooseAlias(validAliases, socket);
        }

        @Override
        public String[] getServerAliases(
                final String keyType, final Principal[] issuers) {
            return this.keyManager.getServerAliases(keyType, issuers);
        }

        @Override
        public String chooseServerAlias(
                final String keyType, final Principal[] issuers, final Socket socket) {
            final Map<String, PrivateKeyDetails> validAliases = getServerAliasMap(keyType, issuers);
            return this.aliasStrategy.chooseAlias(validAliases, socket);
        }

        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getCertificateChain(final String alias) {
            return this.keyManager.getCertificateChain(alias);
        }

        @Override
        public PrivateKey getPrivateKey(final String alias) {
            return this.keyManager.getPrivateKey(alias);
        }

        @Override
        public String chooseEngineClientAlias(
                final String[] keyTypes, final Principal[] issuers, final SSLEngine sslEngine) {
            final Map<String, PrivateKeyDetails> validAliases = getClientAliasMap(keyTypes, issuers);
            return this.aliasStrategy.chooseAlias(validAliases, null);
        }

        @Override
        public String chooseEngineServerAlias(
                final String keyType, final Principal[] issuers, final SSLEngine sslEngine) {
            final Map<String, PrivateKeyDetails> validAliases = getServerAliasMap(keyType, issuers);
            return this.aliasStrategy.chooseAlias(validAliases, null);
        }

    }

}
```

- TextUtils.java

.

```
/**
 * @since 4.3
 */
final class TextUtils {

    /**
     * Returns true if the parameter is null or of zero length
     */
    public static boolean isEmpty(final CharSequence s) {
        if (s == null) {
            return true;
        }
        return s.length() == 0;
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the parameter is null or contains only whitespace
     */
    public static boolean isBlank(final CharSequence s) {
        if (s == null) {
            return true;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (!Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @since 4.4
     */
    public static boolean containsBlanks(final CharSequence s) {
        if (s == null) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i))) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

- TrustAllStrategy.java

.

```
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

/**
 * Created on 2015.06.02..
 */
public class TrustAllStrategy implements TrustStrategy {
    @Override
    public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
            throws CertificateException {
        return true;
    }
}
```

- TrustSelfSignedStrategy.java

.

```
/*
 * ====================================================================
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * [...add this back]
 *
 */   
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

/**
 * A trust strategy that accepts self-signed certificates as trusted. Verification of all other
 * certificates is done by the trust manager configured in the SSL context.
 *
 * @since 4.1
 */
public class TrustSelfSignedStrategy implements TrustStrategy {

    public static final TrustSelfSignedStrategy INSTANCE = new TrustSelfSignedStrategy();

    @Override
    public boolean isTrusted(
            final X509Certificate[] chain, final String authType) throws CertificateException {
        return chain.length == 1;
    }

}
```

- TrustStrategy.java

.

```
/*
 * ====================================================================
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) [...add this back]
 */
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

/**
 * A strategy to establish trustworthiness of certificates without consulting the trust manager
 * configured in the actual SSL context. This interface can be used to override the standard
 * JSSE certificate verification process.
 *
 * @since 4.4
 */
public interface TrustStrategy {
    /**
     * Determines whether the certificate chain can be trusted without consulting the trust manager
     * configured in the actual SSL context. This method can be used to override the standard JSSE
     * certificate verification process.
     * <p/>
     * Please note that, if this method returns {@code false}, the trust manager configured
     * in the actual SSL context can still clear the certificate as trusted.
     *
     * @param chain    the peer certificate chain
     * @param authType the authentication type based on the client certificate
     * @return {@code true} if the certificate can be trusted without verification by
     * the trust manager, {@code false} otherwise.
     * @throws CertificateException thrown if the certificate is not trusted or invalid.
     */
    boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
            throws CertificateException;
}
```

Once you add these, you can build your `SSLContext` like so:

```
       SSLContextBuilder sslContextBuilder = SSLContextBuilder.create();
       KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS", BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
       android.content.res.Resources res = <getter for resources>;
       InputStream inputStream = res.openRawResources(R.raw.cert);           
       keyStore.load(inputStream, trustStorePassword);
       sslContextBuilder.loadTrustMaterial(keyStore, trustStorePassword);
       SSLContext sslContext = sslContextBuilder.build();
       //okHttpClient.setSslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```

EDIT: Testing certificate

```
                keyStore.load(byteArrayInputStream, keyStorePassword);
                Certificate[] certificates = keyStore.getCertificateChain("key-alias"); //you need to know the alias
                if(certificates.length > 0) {
                    Certificate certificate = certificates[0];
                    X509Certificate x509Certificate = (X509Certificate) certificate;
                    Log.d(TAG,
                          "Certificate found with DN [" + x509Certificate.getSubjectDN() + "]");
```

Comment: I'm actually doing that. I forgot to make that change in the original code. I will edit my original question. Sorry about that mixup.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I just woke up and added a bit to my answer, then.

Comment: I think you're just missing ˛`KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS", BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);`

Comment: Tried both with no luck. The only thing I changed (from your full solution) was: sslContextBuilder.loadTrustMaterial(keyStore, trustStorePassword); to sslContextBuilder.loadTrustMaterial(keyStore, TrustSelfSignedStrategy.INSTANCE);

Still handshake failed exception.

Comment: ....wow. This code worked perfectly fine for me when I used it in an `OkHttpClient` instance, which uses the exact same `SSLSocketFactory`. I have no idea what's wrong. Are you sure your BKS keystore is valid?

Comment: I'll try to regenerate the certificate with bouncy castle. Note that this is for SSL for a non-http application. Don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference, OkHttp uses the same underlying SSLSocketFactory and would crash with the same SSL ERROR if something is wrong.

Comment: I re-created the certificate with no luck. I did investigate the above code... seems like it's creating a delegate TrustManagerDelegate and using that to init the SSLContext. Eerily enough, when i put breakpoints on on any of the delegate methods, they never get hit.

Comment: ...I'm sorry, I'm stumped :( this solution I posted here worked for me, but I was using HTTP. I don't know if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you can refer to the following sample code from the Google's tranining docs:

> [Security with HTTPS and SSL](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html)

```
// Load CAs from an InputStream
// (could be from a resource or ByteArrayInputStream or ...)
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
// From https://www.washington.edu/itconnect/security/ca/load-der.crt
InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("load-der.crt"));
Certificate ca;
try {
    ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
    System.out.println("ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
} finally {
    caInput.close();
}

// Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
keyStore.load(null, null);
keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

// Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
tmf.init(keyStore);

// Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

// Tell the URLConnection to use a SocketFactory from our SSLContext
URL url = new URL("https://certs.cac.washington.edu/CAtest/");
HttpsURLConnection urlConnection =
    (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
copyInputStreamToOutputStream(in, System.out);
```

Comment: My mycert.jks is password protected. I also have a mycert.cert (not pw protected) file but seems like in the code above, i can load either one or the other. And neither one works (the .jks file won't even load properly).

Comment: Try convert jks to bks, pls read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312193/does-android-support-jks-keystore-type and other questions available SO. For .cert file, have you tried the link I commented at your question yet? Pay attention to wrappedTrustManagers.