# Which Android versions support BKS?

Tags: java, android, ssl

I need to use SSL sockets in my Android app. I've managed to get it to work, but initially I had some problems with the keystore. On my first try I used a JKS keystore, but apparently that does not work on Android. E.g. the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312193/does-android-support-jks-keystore-type) say that Android only supports BKS.

So I converted my keystore to BKS, and as a result everything seems to work perfectly.

But then I started to worry: Do all versions (or at least reasonably recent versions) of Android support BKS, and is it supported on all devices? Or do I have to add keystores in other formats as well (e.g. JKS, BKS-v1 etc), and check at runtime what version to use? I've tried googling this for some time now, but I'm not able to figure it out.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStore says BKS is supported since Android 1

Comment: @Martheen Thanks, I hadn't notice that! So going with just BKS should be enough, then? I assume it won't be removed anytime soon either?

Comment: The lack of JKS support is due to its proprietary nature, BKS meanwhile has a very permissive license https://bouncycastle.org/LICENSE.html. The last update is the addition of AndroidKeyStore in Android 4.3, over a decade ago and with no depreciation of other types since, so I don't any major changes for your app expected lifetime